# How to access the numerical value of loss and accuracy over the training epoch of a neural network?

Tags: keras

```
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=32 ,epochs=300,
                    validation_data = (X_test, Y_test), verbose=2)



pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

I use the following code (Keras + Tensorflow) to plot my neural network model performance over each training epoch as
[image]

However,Is there anyway to access the data of these 4 performance metric that is loss , accuracy, val_loss, val_accuracy as array (because I want to analyze them latter) ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi. Programming issues are off-topic here. Please, read our on-topic page: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply access the single losses stored in `history.history` with something like

```
history.history['my_loss_name']
```

To know which columns your history data frame has you can do `print(history.history.columns.values)`.